# Different result from my app and test console Facebook

Tags: facebook

Why?
Test console:
[image: test console]

My Application:

[image: application]

Comment: How about some more details? My hunch - you are not logged or authorized...

Comment: uhm... i'm logged.
I must print  my events created by me on my fb account, in external site.. ideas? uff...

Answer (score 0):

Does your app have the user_events permission for your user?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a `permission` difference between your `app` and the `test_console`

You can **see permission details according the access tokens** using this debug tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

On the other hand, I'm experiencing the same problem. I've double checked and made sure that both my `app` and the `test_console` have the same permissions on the user.

My guess is that Facebook can tweak results on there backend for specific application (profile) or maybe according the type of application (web, ...).

If someone has an answer for this I would be grateful!